# How can I change a number to a variable in C?

Tags: c, variables, execl

I would like to know how to substitue the value of a variable in C.

```
execl ("/bin/cat","cat","/proc/30828/status", (char *)0 );
```

I would like to be able to change the "30828" to a variable, because this value isn't fixed. I am wondering if it would be possible to do something like in SHELL where you can do it. For example in shell you can do:

```
K=`ls -lis $i`
echo $K
```

Comment: use snprintf to construct a variable string. Then pass that string to execl.

Answer (score 6):

Use `snprintf()` to substitute the PID into a string variable:

```
char statusfile[30];
sprintf(statusfile, sizeof statusfile, "/proc/%d/status", pid);
execl("/bin/cat","cat",statusfile, (char *)0 );
```